# More than just data communication between threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Say I have 3 threads.

1st Thread is the controller where I create threads
2nd and 3rd is where the data processing is done

The catch is, the 2nd thread does a different operation than the 3rd. So I need a way to differentiate between the two different logic. Would just creating threads with different methods suffice?

No! That's because should thread 2 die, become unresponsive I need the 3rd to take it's place and start doing the job that the 2nd thread was doing, and create a new one to act as the 3rd but creating a new one to act as the 3rd is not my issue.

It's as I said, how to suddenly make the 3rd thread start doing the 2nd one's logic without starting a whole new thread for the previous 2nd thread and resetting it's variables

E.g. Thread 2 dies, Thread 3 now needs to start doing Thread 2's job and I need to create a new Thread to cover for Thread 3.

---

Note: Bonus question is how I can do it without losing the Thread 2 so that in the eventuality that it stops being unresponsive I can still re-use it?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: In whatever struct holds the data, use an enum that any thread can use to run a case switch.  All the threads can then run the same code, and you can control the sequence of operations by setting the enum appropriately so as to instruct the next thread to ruun the desired operation.

Comment: Oh - and if the problem with thread 2 is a bug, fix it!

Answer (score 1):

You picked the wrong tool for the job. If you need to handle a task dying or becoming unresponsive, you must isolate them with processes, not threads.

Threads share an execution environment. So if a thread corrupts or damages that execution environment, it can affect all the other threads. For example, say your thread dies in the process of adjusting shared structures. If you keep the lock on those shared structures, no other thread can ever access them. If you release the lock, other threads may access them and find them in a corrupted state.

Use multiple processes for this kind of isolation.

Comment: Using processes instead of threads is not guaranteed to fix the OP's problem - OP does not know or explain what the problem is with 'thread 2', so using processes may well not help any.

Comment: I might've been unclear then, sorry. What each thread is doing is opening a socket and acting like a "server" where it receives some command and does it on top of the data. The 3rd thread is supposed to be the backup "server" which mimics replicates everything the 2nd thread does on a separate copy of the data, as a fail-safe. But in the eventuality that any of those threads exits i need to restart them. And should for e.g. the 2nd thread ( Main "server" ) exit/die the 3rd thread now needs to perform as the new Main "server".

Comment: @FelipeHeliszkowski Why would the thread exit or die when there's still useful work for it to do? That just sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yes and no, i'm trying to protect it from unexpected errors, so that the rest of the application doesn't break. Should something happen to one of the threads the applications shouldn't break because one thread failed and exited with code -1 but fix what needs to be fixed( E.g Making one thread behave as the one who died and creating a new thread for the old job )